# Why does java gives an error while just writing package-private member of class in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, scope

I have 2 classes R and T in a package i am accessing package-private member of class R in T like this R.x; but this gives an error while this works System.out.println(R.x); why ? i know just R.x; is useless but still curious why is so.

Adding code sample

```
package test;


public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    R obj=new R();
    System.out.println("calling public method of z"+obj.getZ());
    System.out.println("calling protected method of y"+obj.getY());
    System.out.println("calling static public member of z"+R.z);
    System.out.println("calling static protected member of y"+R.y);
    T.x;//this here shows error in eclipse 
    R.z; 
    System.out.println(T.x); // this works fine
}

}

package test;

public class T {

    public final static int z=1;
    protected static int y=2;
    static int x=3;

    public int getZ(){
        return z;
    }

    protected int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    private int getX(){
        return x;
    }
}

  package test;


 public class R extends T{



 }
```

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

The private data members are not accessible outside the class where they are declared/defined even if the access to the private data members happens from another class within the same package. You could refer to access rules for data members here http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/.

Comment: i am accessing package-private member i.e. member with no access modifier like below  public class R { static x; } and accessing it in class T, syso works just fine but just R.x; doesn't

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are working with?